# Can this pull down attic ladder be fixed?

Tags: garage, attic, ladder

Looks like the rivet/flange thing popped out of the square piece.  I don't know how I would get the rivet back in there with the ridge/flange whatever you call it on the end, which I assume is what holds it in there. It also looks like I would have to be in the attic with the ladder pulled to have any hope of connecting that J-shaped bolt back to the spring.

[Here are some pics](https://imgur.com/a/u7yJm)

The last pic is the way it should look.

Comment: The pictures are gone. Please add to the question directly next time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "yes".
Start by removing the quadratic piece of metal with some sort of lever, then place a screw from the "inside" through the hole and check if there is room for a nut to hold the loose part in place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be hesitant to recommend a repair. That point supports weight, and if it fails someone could get hurt. If you're inclined to try a repair anyway use at least grade 8 bolts and some form of lock-nut or doubled nut so that it doesn't loosen in use. And you might as well do the other side too- it's seen exactly the same amount of wear and tear so it's probably going to fail soon otherwise.

Phil